# Accessing attrs in custom view in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-attributes

I am creating a custom view in Kotlin.

For the constructors, I have followed the suggestions listed here: https://blog.q42.nl/the-danger-of-assumptions-kotlin-with-android-custom-views-adb79bf2da45

My problem is that now the init block doesn't recognise the attrs parameter since they are not in the primary constructor.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `@JVMOverloads` constructor works in 99% cases, I have yet to encounter a view that'd work incorrectly with it.

Comment: @Pawel But it is considered dangerous in case changes are made to the base intitalisers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the constructors with bodies and call a function initialising attributes from within.

For example:

```
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    attrs?.let { initAttrs(it) }
}

private fun initAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet) {
    ...
}
```